# Common Lispの引数有りメソッドの書き方

Tags: common-lisp

CLOSを勉強中です。　クラスや引数無しのメソッドは書けるようになったのですが、引数ありのメソッドの書き方が解りません。

下記コードの`square`に高さ`tall`を引数として取り、立方体の体積を求めるメソッドの書き方と呼び出し方を教えて下さい

```lisp
(defclass shape () (
  (width :initform 0 :accessor shape-width :initarg :width)
  (height :initform 0 :accessor shape-height :initarg :height)))

(defclass square (shape) ())
(defmethod area ((x square)) (* (shape-width x) (shape-height x)))
;; 次の行の書き方が解らない
(defmethod cube (?????????????????????????)
  (* (shape-width x) (shape-hight x) tall))


(defclass triangle (shape) ())
(defmethod area ((x triangle)) (/ (* (shape-width x) (shape-height x)) 2))

(defparameter sq (make-instance 'square :width 600 :height 300))
(defparameter tri (make-instance 'triangle :width 600 :height 300))

(format t "~d" (area sq))
(format t "~d" (area tri))
;; 引数ありのメソッドの呼び出し方も解らない
(format t "~d" (cube ???????))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 立方体の体積を求めるメソッドの書き方と呼び出し方

```lisp
(defmethod cube ((x square) tall)
  (* (shape-width x) (shape-height x) tall))

(format t "~d" (cube sq 5))
```

##### 追記

`cuboid` クラスと `volume` メソッドを定義してもよいかと思います。

```lisp
(defclass shape () (
  (width :initform 0 :accessor shape-width :initarg :width)
  (height :initform 0 :accessor shape-height :initarg :height)))

(defclass square (shape) ())
(defmethod area ((x square)) (* (shape-width x) (shape-height x)))

(defclass cuboid (square)
  ((tall :initform 0 :accessor cuboid-tall :initarg :tall)))
(defmethod volume ((x cuboid)) (* (area x) (cuboid-tall x)))

(defparameter cub (make-instance 'cuboid :width 600 :height 300 :tall 5))
(volume cub)
```